# Resizing the backbuffer of a swap chain (DX9)

Tags: c++, winforms, directx, directx-9

new on this forum (first post)

I'll post the image as its the easiest way to explain:
http://i42.tinypic.com/zvbj9i.png (cant post image because I dont have 10 rep yet)
The swap chains are being rendered onto resizable panels, but on resize, some of them go very.. pixelly. Heres the main rendering code: http://pastebin.com/uG9sLE1r
Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks,
James Warner

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue, the .x portion (stores widths) of the D3DXVECTOR2 that was storing sizes of the panels was being assigned to the height property of the backbuffer. Working 100% now. Heres my code for anyone that might find it useful: http://pastebin.com/VvmUZNXF